# Application Exit Control

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, exit-code

I have created a Windows Application using C# (.NET Framework v4.0). The application purpose is a variety of Third Party Application API Integration into a single one.

Currently, I am facing an issue where the client starts the API requests. Due to some reason like Internet slowness the API Response takes a bit longer. *The user closes the application* using the Red Application Exit Button or in some rare cases uses Task Manger to exit the application.

Issue now persists like, the API Request is processes succesfully in their side but before the response has been read in our side the Application has been closed and looses the thread and does not reflect in our side.

Is there any method through which we can control this application Exit ? Can we block this application exit especially when the API Reqest is in process.

***Solution Under Implementation***

- Use a Global Variable when the application API Request is in progress.
- Use the MDI Form OnClosing event trigger to check the status of the variable and block the Application Exit.

*This method will not block the Task Manager application close scenario.*

Is there any possible method which can be implemented to block this issue or a better method which can substantially reduce this specific error from my application.

Comment: `form.FormClosing` event gives the reason for the close.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to prevent a user from *killing* a running application through task manager.

Task Manger's kill command is designed to kill a hanging application (no matter what it is doing in this moment)

Best solution: Avoid hanging of your app, provide clean ways to exit your app. Educate your users to use task manager as a (very) last resort only.

Comment: How can this app hanging be avoided. In scenatios where the Internet connection is slow i could not implement a solution. The issue is happending in very limitter number of situations but still it reflects like Dirty API.

Comment: This is another interesting question for SO. generally: make all time consuming/long running tasks _asynchronous_. The details are beyond the scope of this comment